# create an array type from a string union type

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to take a string union type and use it to create a readonly array type basically given the following:

```
type Params = {
  a: string,
  b: number
}

type ParamKeys = keyof Params
```

I'd like to get the following type:

```
Readonly<['a', 'b']>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You're looking to convert a union type (`type ParamKeys = "a" | "b")` to a tuple (`["a" | "b"]`). It _should_ be possible (adapt the solution from https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901 and wrap it with `Readonly`), but no built-in solutions yet (e.g. a `tupleof` operator as suggested by the initial GitHub issue.